# \addplot doesn't work outside of tikzpicture or axis environment

Tags: pgfplots

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{axis}
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.5,0) -- ++(11,0) node[below left]{$t$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.5) -- ++(0,7) node[below right]{$s(t)$};
    \end{axis}
    \addplot{
   [domain=0:2*pi,samples=40,smooth,
    thick,blue]
   {sin(deg(x))};}
\end{document}
```

When I run this code, I have this error: Undefined control sequence.

Comment: You are missing an `axis` environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the syntax in the [pgfplots manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.5,0) -- ++(11,0) node[below left]{$t$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.5) -- ++(0,7) node[below right]{$s(t)$};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=40,smooth, thick,blue]{sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```